# Verifying Property of Constructed Brownian Motion using Haar Basis

Tags: probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

This is an alternative proof to the construction of BM (to the one using Kolmogorov Extension), called Lévy construction. Let us define the Haar basis as $H_{k,l}$ and $Z_{k,l}\sim N(0,1)$ as IID random variables. Then define $G_k(t)=\sum_{l=0}^{2^{n-1}}Z_{k,l}\int_0^t H_{k,l}(s)ds$, and let our construction of Brownian motion be:

$$W_t=\sum_{k-1}^\infty G_k(t)$$

Recall that the Haar basis is $H_{k,l}(t)=2^{k/2}$ or $-2^{k/2}$ on alternating $2^{-k-1}$-length sub-intervals on the interval $[0,1]$.

What I don't understand is how this respects the property of BM, that is, $(B_t - B_s)$ is independent, mean 0, normally distributed of variance $(t-s)$. If we take, for example, $t=1/2$ and $s=0$, the above construction would include both the $G_2$ path of $N(0,1)/\sqrt{2}=N(0,1/2)$ and well as half of the $G_1$ path of $N(0,1)$ (the remaining paths vanishing to 0). Any clarification would be appreciated (and lmk if any is needed from my end).

Answer (score 1):

This is shown in [The Haar functions and the Brownian motion](https://math.stanford.edu/%7Eryzhik/STANFORD/STANF227-10/notes-bm.pdf) and [Construction of Brownian Motion using Haar wavelets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2096771/construction-of-brownian-motion-using-haar-wavelets). For $t>s$ we have

$$W_t-W_s=\sum_{k-1}^\infty G_k(t)-G_k(s)=\sum_{k-1}^\infty \sum_{l=0}^{2^{n-1}}Z_{k,l}\int_{s}^{t} H_{k,l}(r)dr.$$

Let $\Phi_{k,l}(s,t):=\int_{s}^{t} H_{k,l}(r)dr$. We study the correlation $t>s, v>u$

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}((W(t)-W(s))(W(v)-W(u))) &\stackrel{1}{=} \lim_{N \to \infty} \mathbb{E}((W_N(t)-W_N(s))(W_N(v)-W_N(u))) \\ &\stackrel{2}{=} \lim_{N \to \infty} \mathbb{E} \left( \sum_{m,n=1}^N\sum_{z,l}  \Phi_{m,z}(s,t)\Phi_{n,l}(u,v) Z_{m,z}Z_{n,l} \right) \\ &\stackrel{3}{=} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{l} \Phi_{n,l}(s,t)\Phi_{n,l}(u,v) \\ &\stackrel{4}{=} \int_0^1 1_{[s,t)}(x) 1_{[u,v)}(x) \, dx. \end{align*}$$

For step 3 we used iid and for step 4 we used the orthonormality of the Haar basis. The right-hand side equals $0$ if $[s,t) \cap [u,v) = \emptyset$; this shows that $W(t)-W(s)$ and $W(v)-W(u)$ are uncorrelated; hence, independent, as these form a Gaussian vector.

Reference: Schilling & Partzsch: Brownian Motion - An Introduction to Stochastic Processes, Section 3.1.